# Как заполнить массив символов (char)через цикл?

Tags: c++

У меня есть массив char на 10 элементов. Как реализовать через цикл его заполнения?

Пример:

```
char one[14];
for(int i=0;i<14;i++){
cin>>one[i];
}
 one[14]//Oleg
//Вывод например имени который записался в этот масив
```

Comment: Символ `one[14]` уже *за выделенным массивом** (последний valid это `one[13]`). И еще, если вы хотите выводить эти данные как строку, то последним символом, после введенных д.б. 0. Т.о. получаем что-то вроде `for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) { cin >> one[i]; one[i + 1] = 0;} cout << one << '\n';`

Comment: Ваш код он считивает по дному символу ввода а мне нужно чтоб ввести строку но в масиве оно отдельно записивалось.

Comment: Вы тогда текст (и заголовок) вопроса приведите в соответствие со своими пожеланиями

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала немного теории. В C++ тип char - это массив из кодом ASCII (насчет кодировки могу ошибиться) символов. Допустим мы объявили и инициализировали массив char с 6 символами:

```
char my_string[6] = "Hello";
```

"Под капотом" массив выглядит примерно так:

```
{72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 0}
```

В этом легко можно убедиться:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    std::cout << static_cast<int> (my_string[i]) << "\n";
} // выведет числа выше, кроме 0
```

Насчет 0 стоит сделать ремарку - это символ окончания строки и при вводе/инициализации он неявно добавляется в конец массива.

Если вы хотите заполнить массив символами из консоли не посимвольно, а **сразу строкой**, то самый простой способ - это объявить массив типа char и заполнить его через std::cin :

```
char my_string[6]; // объявлияем массив char из 5 элементов (шестой - символ окончания строки)
std::cin >> my_string; // заполняем массив из консоли

for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // При вводе "Hello" выведет Hello
    std::cout << my_string[i] << "\n"; // А введенное слово посимвольно
} // запишется в массив my_string
```

Однако здесь кроется опасность. Поскольку в C++ длина данных массивов должна быть задана константной переменной во время компиляции (обычно это литерал), то вы не можете заранее предугадать длину введенного пользователем сообщения. А если сообщение будет больше, чем массив char, то сообщение обрежется, а в конце выполнения программы выдаст ошибку о повреждении стека памяти.

Простой и неэффективный способ избежать этого - объявить массив больше потенциального сообщения пользователя:

```
char my_string[255];
```

А вообще лучше использовать std::string для подобных целей:

```
std::string my_string; // объявление
std::cin >> my_string; // ввод
std::cout << my_string; // Вывод
```

Comment: К столь обстоятельному ответу, все же, как минимум, следует добавить, что `cin >> str;` введет *не целую строку, а первое слово в ней* (последовательность "непробельных" (т.е. не содержащих пробел, табуляцию и т.п.) символов). И, конечно же, если размер слова будет больше, чем размер массива, то оно *не обрежется*, а считается полностью, при этом попортив память (т.е. содержимое других переменных, расположенных в памяти за массивом (в более старших адресах))

Comment: Благодарю за поправку. Сам еще в ++ новичек, так что в некоторых аспектах могу ошибаться)